# Index of object in array which has array of one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working with Google Maps API in Angular (TypeScript). I want to make clickable map of countries, where you click some country it changes color. Seems easy but I'm using ng2-google-maps library for Angular which is a little bit complicated.

My problem:
I need to get index of main object in array. But I need to search by value which is in this object as another object in another array.

[image: console.log of those array]

I already get country code of clicked region in map. for example "PL" like in this console.log.

I need to get index of main array (PL has '0' index) to check if PL country already exists in this array.

I tried like this:

```
mainArray.findIndex((result) => result.c.findIndex((result) => result.v === 'PL'));
```

But it doesn't work. Then I'll need to use probably slice() method to delete found index from main array.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) within the function which returns index or `-1` so it will be falsy in case element is at position `0` and all other cases it will be truthy(non-zero numbers are truthy) so it won't work as you expected.

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which returns true if condition satisfied for at least one element.

```
 mainArray.findIndex((result) => result.c.some((result) => result.v === 'PL'));
```